# What does it actually mean when authors say "AngularJS has compiled the DOM"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going through ***Lukas Ruebbelke's*** [AngularJS in Action](http://www.manning.com/books/angularjs-in-action),

The author puts at many places throughout the book,

A ***view*** in AngularJS is the ***HTML*** after it has been ***compiled by AngularJS***.

I seriously don't understand what is the role of the ***compilation process*** and what really happens behind the scenes?

Or does it has something to do with the ***act of gluing*** the ***HTML*** and the ***controllers*** with the ***scope***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the author of the book, which he explained in the coming chapter:

Just think of ***compilation*** as ***gluing the HTML and controllers together with the scope***.

[image]

The AngularJS compilation cycle happens in 2 parts:

```
1) the compilation phase and,
2) the linking phase.
```

[image]

[image]

When the HTML is fully loaded, ***AngularJS parses the DOM*** and ***compiles*** a list of all of the ***AngularJS directives***; this is known as compilation phase. Once full inventory has been made of the HTML, AngularJS enters the ***linking phase, which is responsible for linking the AngularJS pieces to an appropriate scope instances***.

Once the ***AngularJS template*** has been linked with its appropriate ***controller via scope***, the bindings become active and the two(***view & controller***) can communicate.

[image]

The compilation process is implicit, and the linking b/w the AngularJS templates and scope is seamless, but you can also manually compile templates and scope together. The need to actually do this is abit of an edge case, but the function call is surprisingly effective at illustrating what's happening.

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

In the method call, we're taking the contents of a HTML element and zipping it up with a scope object.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS Compiling  works in different  way. It directly works on HTML DOM rather than strings and manipulate it as required. It uses **two way data-binding** between model and view to sync your data.

Agular's HTML compiler allows  to attach new behaviors or attributes to any HTML element. Angular calls these behaviors as directives.
AngularJS compilation process takes place in the web browser; no server side or pre-compilation step is involved. Angular use $compiler service to compile your Angular HTML page.

The angular' compilation process begins after your HTML page (static DOM) is fully loaded. It happens in two phases :

**1.Compile**

It traverse the DOM and collect all of the directives. The result is a linking function.

**2.Link**

It combine the directives with a scope and produce a live view. Any changes in the scope model are reflected in the view, and any user interactions with the view are reflected in the scope model.
The concept of compile and link comes from C, where you first compile the code and then link it to actually execute it. The process is very much similar in AngularJS as well.

So we can say that, A **view** in AngularJS is the **HTML** after it has been compiled by **AngularJS.**

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you already read the official documentation from Angular about [the compilation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) but I can already give you my understanding of the topic.

Yes, it is actually the glue between the controller which holds the data in the scope with the HTML of your template. Basically, it does what a templating engine (MustacheJS and co.) does: the compiler actually matches your variable within your HTML template with their corresponding value in the scope. 
It does more like compiling your directives but you can read more on this in the documentation.